# Modify Product Listing 'Add to Cart' button

Tags: magento-1.8, magento-enterprise, product-list

I'm building a self contained module which will make modifications to the 'Add to Cart' button through Magento's listing and detail pages. I can easily modify the button on the detail page as it uses it's own template addtocart.phtml.

Where as the listing page has the mark up for these buttons embedded in a chunk of HTML. The code for the button is below.

```
<?php if($_product->isSaleable()): ?>
    <p><button type="button" title="<?php echo $this->__('Add to Cart') ?>" class="button btn-cart" onclick="setLocation('<?php echo $this->getAddToCartUrl($_product) ?>')"><span><span><?php echo $this->__('Add to Cart') ?></span></span></button></p>
<?php else: ?>
    <p class="availability out-of-stock"><span><?php echo $this->__('Out of stock') ?></span></p>
<?php endif; ?>
```

My issue is trying to modify the above code without having to ask the installer to make numerous code changes. Obviously if the site is running a heavily modified template they will need to.

I could provide a new list.phtml template and override the entirety of the file but this seems like it's going to cause more issues then it's worth.

Short of writing some dirty hack to attempt to locate this button and make the modifications is there a better solution? What would you suggest to be the best solution in a contained module as well?

Comment: I don't think there's a clean way to do it.

Comment: @Tim it's a real shame having to inform customers they're going to have to edit code to get the module to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your definition of dirty is a bit much, since each block registers an event that allows you to modify it's HTML after it's processed it itself. And then there's JavaScript as well.

In fact, I'd say the clean way **is** to use this [core_block_abstract_to_html_after event](http://alanstorm.com/magento_listener_lifecycle_block), because rewriting the template to include another template for this button, causes much more overhead. Instead in `core_block_abstract_to_html_after` you can do a single `preg_replace` pass, or a maybe somewhat cleaner DOM replacement.

Comment: This wouldn't be a reliable way of always replacing the button. As it's known for people to edit core templates if they're uncertain of what they're doing. I don't think there is a clean solution that won't require the user to make a number of modifications to their templates.

I do like your logic though.

Comment: Well, let me put it this way. Anyone hacking the template that removes the btn-cart from the class definition is shooting him/herself in the foot. :) So there would be your foothold. Oh, and the feet in this comment are coincidental.

Comment: You do make a very valid point. Thanks for the response.

Comment: I ended up using the Zend_Dom_Query() class to allow great modifications to the DOM.