# Remove Add To Cart Button in product List page magento2 without using template file

Tags: magento2, product-list, addtocart, list.phtml

I want to remove Add To Cart button at category page. but I don't want to use template file. I did it for product view page using event.

```
    $layout = $observer->getEvent()->getLayout();
    $layout->getUpdate()->addUpdate('<referenceBlock name="product.info.addtocart.additional" remove="true"/>');
    $layout->getUpdate()->load();
    $layout->generateXml();
```

its working fine; But how can i remove button from category page?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If we look at this `module-catalog\view\frontend\templates\product\list.phtml` around line `80` There is function `$_product->isSaleable()` which then again call to `isSalable()` function of Magento\Catalog\Model\Product.

There are two events in it `catalog_product_is_salable_before` and `catalog_product_is_salable_after`. Depending on your need you can modify it.

I used `catalog_product_is_salable_after` event to hide `Add to Cart` button

```
namespace Namespace\Module\Observer\Frontend;

use Magento\Framework\Event\Observer;
use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;

class classname implements ObserverInterface
{
    public $request;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http $request
    ) {
        $this->request = $request;
    }

    public function execute(Observer $observer)
    {
        if ($this->request->getFullActionName() == 'catalog_category_view')
        {

            $product = $observer->getEvent()->getProduct();
            $saleble = $observer->getEvent()->getSalable();

            if($product->getTypeId() == 'customProductType')
            {
                $saleble->setIsSalable(false);
                $salable = $product->getStatus() == \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Attribute\Source\Status::STATUS_ENABLED;
                if ($salable && $product->hasData('is_salable')) {
                    $salable = $product->getData('is_salable');
                }
                $product->setIsSaleable($salable);                        
            }
        }
        return $this;
    }
}
```

Though this will add `In Stock` or `Out of Stock` in place of `Add to Cart`.

Comment: but it also hides product options

Answer (score 0):

You can use `core_layout_render_element` **Event** from the `Magento\Framework\View\Layout::renderElement()` method in order to add an **Observer**. In the observer you can you `preg_replace` or analogue to remove generated **Add to Cart** button.

There is similar question and however event name is outdated: [Modify Product Listing 'Add to Cart' button](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/19197/modify-product-listing-add-to-cart-button?rq=1)

Hope it helps.

Comment: it's for magento 1 not magento2

Answer (score -1):

You can achieve this by following CSS tricks.

Add below CSS rules in `skin/theme/child/css` or `skin/theme/default/css`

```
/*add to cart button*/
.products-grid .button.btn-cart {
    display : none ;
}
```

Comment: This is not suggested as it still renders in frontend and we can access it easily with browser tools. Css has to be used only for client end events such as show/hide etc. Never use to hide something which is restricted for users always.